# Using Ext JS in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, extjs

I don’t have advanced knowledge in JavaScript, and I am trying to learn how to use Ext JS framework in ASP.NET (C# or VB.NET) environment. I’ve got couple of samples, but was unable get the project working. Is there such as website or book so I can go a read up about Ext JS in more details and how can I include this into my website?

Comment: Don't ask people to e-mail answers to you.  That defeats the purpose of this site.  I deleted your e-mail address from the post.

Answer (score 7):

Mike,

The best example site out there is http://examples.extjs.eu/.  Each example has a link for viewing HTML, javascript and CSS separately.

We are successfully integrating ExtJS with the ASP.NET MVC framework.  A separate post detailing how to put everything together is probably in order.

Comment: Please do not forget to update the comments with the link to the separate post

Comment: Come on, please, man, I've been waiting for the separate post for 7 years already...

Comment: I can't imagine you are serious about this AND I haven't looked at that code in 3 jobs and 6+ years. 

This is the best I can do
https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?252644

Answer (score 6):

And this one: http://extaspnet.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 5):

Also see http://www.coolite.com/ (Just providing the link and in no way endorsing it, as I haven't really seen it in action.)

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you've been all through the samples at
*[Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/)*

You really need to read this entire post *[Secrets of the JavaScript Ninjas](https://blog.codinghorror.com/secrets-of-the-javascript-ninjas/)* (2008-08-13) to decide if Ext JS is a better choice.

If you decide to stick with Ext JS , you may find *[Ext JS Extender Controls](http://www.codeplex.com/ExtJsExtenderControl)* useful.

Comment: ExtJsExtenderControl is a ASP.NET wrapper around ExtJS which in turn is a wrapper for DOM, sounds leaky to me... But hey, still a choice.

Comment: The first link seems to be broken now.

Answer (score 2):

When I was learning to incorporate Ext JS with ASP.NET at my previous position, I found the best way to learn it (aside from the documentation and examples) was just going thru the forums and picking up up sample code here and there from user posts.

Once you've learned the nuances of the client API (and their online documentation and forums have been excellent in this regard), it's then just a simple matter of having your ASP.NET code returning the correct JSON for Ext JS to consume.

I have a rather outdated ASP.NET MVC / Ext JS sample project that probably won't compile anymore (it was built with an early preview release of MVC) but you can probably still go thru the code to see how Ext JS interacts with the server side code.

[Ext JS and ASP.NET MVC Sample Project](http://www.redgreenrefactor.com/post/Ext-Js-and-ASPNET-MVC.aspx)

Comment: Woops - the link seems to be down for me

Comment: yes the link is broken !!!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Script#](http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp/)  project. It, at build time, generates JavaScript from your C# and is particularly good for writing desktop-like applications.

Answer (score 2):

I worked on a project that was using ExtJS heavily. I don't really know what king of problems do you actually have but we used a great combination of ExtJS, Asp.net, WCF for ExtJS Ajax calls to the server. Worked like a charm. But we abandoned the regular asp.net control usage almost completely, because most of the UI was build in ExtJS. We also used our own layout and controls with a different look and feel than ExtJS. So it didn't really look like an ExtJS app.

You could get by with regular WebMethods (as in Web Services) as well.

You will definitelly benefit a lot by using tools like **Firebug** and **Fiddler** to debug your javascript code and to examine all messages going back and forth between client and server.

Getting examples is better and better every day, since more and more people are using ExtJS in combination with various technologies. Asp.net as well.

Comment: Ditto. Use Firebug and don't use ASP.NET's control library, and it works just fine. I use ExtJS on the UI for 5 apps I maintain currently, all with ASP.NET 3.5 on the back end.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the following website is more relavent.

http://www.ext.net/

It provides community as well as pro version, and it just works well.

Answer (score 1):

Any particular reason you've settled on Ext JS out of all the different frameworks out there?  If not, since you're using ASP.NET I recommend jQuery instead as it's going to be officially supported by Microsoft soon.

Comment: Also jQuery uses the more liberal MIT license than ExtJS which uses the GPLv3.

Comment: ExtJS's Core library, which is the best comparison to JQuery, is released under an MIT license, not GPL.

But ExtJS does a LOT more than JQuery does, so you're comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: But ExtJs provides two different thing, ExtUI and ExtCore and they are different. ExtCore is counterpart of jQuery but ExtUI is greater than jQueryUI

Answer (score 0):

i wrote a [post](http://thekindofme.wordpress.com/2009/02/05/a-grid-with-ajax-pagination-sorting-filtering-on-aspnet-mvc-with-extjs-and-ef/) on using extjs grid with asp.net mvc. although you are not planning to  use ext on mvc fm. i think other details like how to render it using javascript, parsing parameters in requests sent by the grid, json serialization...etc will be relavant and helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

The best ASP.Net MVC Tag Library for the popular ExtJS framework. 
Website:http://www.mvcnext.com

MVCnExt simplifies ExtJs for ASP.Net MVC.

Makes it easier for to integrate ExtJs compoments for ASP.Net MVC.

Answer (score 0):

The best implementation of ExtJS over MVC I have found at http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?t=72245 . It is not too superfluously implemented but it's enough mature.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a [look here](http://extsharp.codeplex.com.) The project contains an ExtJS 3.3.1 import library for Script# compiler which you can use to code your ExtJS scripts in C#.