# How can I handle a JSON result in JavaScript (on MVC)?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm using [Ext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_JS) in a MVC project. I wrote a controller, like the code below. How do I handle this JSON reult in my JavaScript used in my View page?

```
    public ActionResult Index() 
    {
        List<PriceList> newList = new List<PriceList>
        {
             new PriceList { Number = 1, Price = 24},
             new PriceList { Number = 2, Price = 25},
             new PriceList { Number = 3, Price = 20},
             new PriceList { Number = 4, Price = 18},
        };

        return Json(newList);
    }
```

Comment: See: * *[Integration Ext JS and ASP.NET MVC](http://geekswithblogs.net/lszk/archive/2009/08/25/integration-extjs-and-asp.net-mvc.aspx)* * Stack Overflow question *[Using Ext JS in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205720/using-extjs-in-asp-net)*

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Using Ext JS in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205720/using-extjs-in-asp-net)*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery templates. An example is *[Introducing jQuery Templates 1: First Steps](http://www.borismoore.com/2010/09/introducing-jquery-templates-1-first.html)* .