# Asp.net 2 with Extjs 4 Grid CRUD example

Tags: c#, asp.net, extjs4

I am a beginner to Extjs 4. I am using C# Asp.Net 2.0. I know how to set Grid for get (json reading) but i dont know how to send save, update, delete command from my Grid and catch that in C# Asp.Net.

Can anybody provide a demo of simple table?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Extjs only with asp.net classic I recommend to use http://www.ext.net .

I started use Ext.js with asp.net and faced a lot of problem, then I discovered them and start use it from version 0.4 (now it's 2.0).

If you don't want, the suggestion is to interface client pages with ashx handlers and invoke them via store.sync().

Another solution (I tried years ago) is to manually create asp.net post via __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) asp.net client function within your store events for each CRUD method.

Stefano

Answer (score 0):

Here is [example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/ExtJS__WebServices.aspx) of Extjs and .Net web service communication, also see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205720/using-extjs-in-asp-net).

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Dextop demos](http://dextop.codaxy.com/showcase/#RowEditableGridWindow) too. Although it requires .NET 4, you'll probably find something useful there.

Comment: Thank you guys for you informative reponses.

I am trying to use EXTJS 4 GRID with rest proxy, after store.save() i cannot caught any field in C# asp.net.

i have checked Request["client_name"], Request.QueryString["client_name"] etc.

Question in which parameter does extjs 4 Rest proxy send fields data so i can caugh that in my asp.net.

Can any body put some light on it